# error while trying to call a python function through js

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm trying to call a python function through my js program, and i'm experiencing error:

```
eel.say_hello_py is not a function
```

I just tried step by step of their docs and its not working, dont know why, what i'm missing?

my python program contains:

```
import eel

eel.init('web')
eel.start('index.html', mode='chrome-app')


@eel.expose                         # Expose this function to Javascript
def say_hello_py(x):
    print('Hello from %s' % x)
```

my html contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<title>Document</title> </head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script> </body>
</html>
```

my index.js file contains:

```
eel.say_hello_py("Javascript World!"); // Call a Python function
```

my files construction:

```
web(folder)
   -> index.html
   -> index.js
python.py
```

what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find fast solution, moved the

> eel.start('index.html', mode='chrome-app')

line, after the expose command.

```
import eel

eel.init('web')

@eel.expose                         # Expose this function to Javascript
def say_hello_py(x):
    print('Hello from %s' % x)

eel.start('index.html', mode='chrome-app')
```